# Page keeps refreshing after fetch().then() with promise (e.preventDefault() is set)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api, youtube-dl

Hello I'm building a simple API using ytdl with express, the route in question downloads a file

```
app.post('/audio', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Downloading audio from ${req.body.url}`);
    downloadAudio(req.body.url)
        .then(i => res.send())
        .catch(e => console.log(e));

    // setTimeout(() => {
    //     res.send();
    // }, 3000);
    // console.log('Audio');
    // console.log(req.body.url, ' - ', req.body.format);
});
```

This is the download audio function

```
const downloadAudio = url => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ytdl.getInfo(url)
            .then(({ title }) => {
                const stream = ytdl(url);
                const proc = new ffmpeg({ source: stream });
                proc.save(`./public/downloads/${title}.mp3`);
                resolve();
                console.log(title);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Custom error');
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};
```

The problem comes from this fetch

```
// 'http://localhost:5000/audio' is the first fetch argument
fetch(`${API_URL}/${format}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: jsonVideo,
        header: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
        .then(res => {
            $button.textContent = 'Download';
            $button.removeAttribute('disabled');
            console.log('Done', res);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

After getting the response, the page just reloads after doing what's inside the then()
In the route above, if I use setTimeout for testing, it waits for 3 seconds then sends the response and the program works as expected without refreshing the page but if I use the promises it shows the response in devtools for a second but reloads the page
Keep in mind I have `e.preventDefault()` on the first line of the event listener in which that fetch is included.

https://github.com/jbordalo/youtube-dloader

Thanks

## Edit

```
app.post('/audio', (req, res) => {
    console.log('/AUDIO');
    console.log(`Downloading audio from ${req.body.url}`);

    res.send({ message: 'doing it' });

    // downloadAudio(req.body.url, (error, result) => {
    //     if (error) {
    //         console.log(error);
    //     } else {
    //         console.log(result);
    //         res.send({ message: result });
    //     }
    // });

});
```

This works but if I uncomment the downloadAudio and remove the first send it starts refreshing again after the response arrives at the console (devtools)

Comment: Please include the rest of the code.

Comment: I've added the github repo link, src/utils/download.js is messy cause I was trying different things

Comment: I've tried changing the functions in download to use callback (since setTimeout doesn't make the page refresh) but it still refreshes whenever I use the actual function downloadVideo()

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` should prevent the default reload. I can't think of any way that `fetch()` could cause a reload by itself.

Comment: I've just changed it to a simple res.send() and it works but as soon as I add the downloadAudio it starts reloading after the fetch. I can only assume it's some problem with the promises/callbacks, maybe a misuse of the ffmpeg lib but I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Added a further example to the question for clarity

Comment: I'm contemplating changing career. The bug was simple. downloadAudio function was downloading  file and that file was being saved inside public dir which live-server was watching so after the change it refreshed the page..

Comment: Nothing in your server code will affect weather or not the browser refreshes the page. You can completely remove the `app.post()` and `downloadAudio()` parts from your question because they are irrelevant

Comment: Also, the code that contains the bug is most likely the event handler in your front-end. All we see is `Keep in mind I have e.preventDefault() on the first line` and that's not enough code to debug

Comment: I was using live-server and that was watching the public folder for changes so as to restart every time I changed a file. The download was saving the a folder inside public which made it refresh since it was a change. Easy as that. Changed download location and it worked

Answer (score 1):

In fetch, you have to add two .then's, one for converrting the returned promise to a text or json, and the other for the actual result.

So the above should be fixed by doing:

```
fetch(`${API_URL}/${format}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: jsonVideo,
        header: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res => {
            $button.textContent = 'Download';
            $button.removeAttribute('disabled');
            console.log('Done', res);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

**EDIT**

If that doesn't work, you can always make an inline iframe using Blob URLs, fetch the data in the iframe, and postMessage it back to the mainframe (and hide the iframe from view), that way if the page refreshes the user will never know. For example:

```js
function c(s) {
    return s.split("&lt;").join("<").split("&gt;").join(">").split("&amp;").join("&")
}

var asdf = document.createElement("iframe");
asdf.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([c(tt.innerHTML)], {
    type:"text/html"

}))
asdf.addEventListener("load", () => {
 asdf.contentWindow.postMessage(23, "*")
});
document.body.appendChild(asdf);
addEventListener("message", e => /*do something with fetched data */console.log(e.data))
```

```html
<textarea style="display:none"id="tt">
 <b id="gf">asdf</b>
 <script>
 document.write(2134);
 window.addEventListener("message", e => {
  gf.innerHTML = Date.now();
  fetch(`${API_URL}/${format}`, {
   headers: {
    "content-type":"application/json"
    
   },
   method:"POST",
                    body: jsonVideo
  }).then(r=>r.text()).then(r => {
   
   e.source.postMessage(r);
  });
 })
 </script>
</textarea>
```

Comment: That does not change the behavior of the program whatsoever, the page still refreshes and the output was not being used anyway.

Comment: @JoãoBordalo and BTW even if the output isn't being usd it still could be useful just for knowing when it finished, or if there was an error or not (which might display in the JSON text itself)

Comment: The bug was completely unrelated but thanks for the answer anyway, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the html code?.

I also had a similar issue with fetch api. In my case, I was using fetch api after click event on the login button in login form.
[Login form preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jqhu.png)

**login form HTML code:**

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    
    <form >
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" >Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name='email' id='email'>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name='pass'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" id='login'>
                Login
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    
</div>
```

As the button is inside the form, so on click it is by default submitting the action.
So two actions were being performed. first is (reaction of form action attribute), second is using fetch api in JS.